# OperationalError: no such table (can't find solution)

Tags: django

Many questions here with same issue, and I followed the instructions to solve the issue in all those questions but failed.

My problem started when I changed a table name, I had one record in that table, I didn't delete that record and used makemigrations, and then migrate. I received an error of "no such table", then I followed some instructions, including:

- flush (to drop the tables)
- deleted migration folder, and recreated it with init file
- clear migration history using fake  zero

None of the above worked for me, I can make the migration, but when I migrate, at first instance it says no changes detected, when I make migration again, then migrate, it says no such table exists (always mentions the table that I changed the name of)

I'm wondering if there are any other solutions I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Delete the `db.sqlite3` file at project folder. After doing this, I managed to migrate without any issues.